# Python Parallelize For-Loop to Pull Images and Write to File

Tags: python, parallel-processing

```
for item in tqdm(items):
     ...  # pull image and save to file
     file.writerow([result])  # write filename to a csv
```

For the above code, items contains hundreds of thousands of elements. That's why I want to parallelize this task. Is there a way to split my for-loop and write to this file safely?

Inside the for-loop, I have to pull an image and save it to file. When I write to file, I only save the image's filename. Also, writing to file does not need to be in order.

Comment: Long story short: you can use concurrent.futures.ProcesPoolExecutor to process the files in parallel with a fixed number of workers and multiprtocessing.Queue to get the filename back into the main process.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your big workload is pulling the images and saving them to a file, you should split the task in two:
-first parallelize  pulling and saving each image as above comment, keeping filename in memmory
-then save these filenames to the file.
As long as I know, writing a file can not be parallelized, so keeping it in your for-loop may cause a bottleneck.